# Sending an HTTPS-Request from an Azure Function to a Server that presents a self-signed Certificate

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, ssl-certificate

I am desperately trying to establish a secure TLS connection from an Azure Function (S1, Windows, Powershell) to a Server that uses a certificate that was signed by a private CA.

Unfortunately, I have no power over the CertStore underneath my Azure Function workers thus I can not add any further root CA certificates to trust. From what I understand this is only possible with an ASE v3 (App Service Environment) infrastructure. However, this set-up is kind of overkill for my use-case as ASEv3 is usually used for applications that are required to be highly isolated and deal with huge workloads.

In my case, I only want to communicate with a third party web server that authenticates with a privately signed certificate.

Naturally I tried to send the web request with powershell using
Invoke-Restmethod and Invoke-Webrequest with the -SkipCertificateCheck parameter. However, this did not work - I still cant establish a secure connection to the server.

`"The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot"`

I also tried implementing a Custom SSL Validation Callback by assembling a Chain of the issuing CA certificates and using this to validate the server certificate, however I could not get it to work either.

Has anyone ever had a similar problem and was able to solve it? There has to be a way, right?

Thank you very much for your time in advance.

Comment: can add a custom CA certificate to your Azure Function by following the instructions in the Azure API Management documentation[1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/api-management/api-management-howto-ca-certificates.md). You can also create and deploy certificates for cloud services and for authenticating with the management API in Azure[2](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/cloud-services/cloud-services-certs-create.md).

Comment: . If you want to generate a self-signed certificate with a custom root CA, you can follow the instructions in the Azure Application Gateway documentation[3](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/application-gateway/self-signed-certificates.md).